# How to display image in model instance in django admin instead of image path

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am writing a Django web app and I'm having a problem with displaying an image in existing model instance in Django admin and I hope you will be able to help me with it.

I have a model with ImageField, when I upload an image to my model it is properly uploaded but instead of displaying the image in admin page there is path to the image displayed, please see screenshot:
[django admin screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wf6gf.png)

Instead of a path I would like to display actual image.
I checked with multiple solutions but I was only able to find an instructions how to display a thumbnail in a page listing all model instances.
Could you advise me?

Comment: Although I'm sure there's a better solution, you could code your own custom admin site instead. What you describe is easily accomplished with Javascript.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your `admin.py`

```
...
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

...

class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude('img') # this is the name of the actual image field in your model
    read_only_fields = ['image'] # this is the field you're defining below
    def image(self, obj):
        return mark_safe('<img src="{url}" width={"width"} height={"height"} />'.format(
            url=obj.img.url, # once again, this is the name of the actual image field in your model
            width=obj.img.width, # or define custom width
            height=obj.img.height, # same as above
            ))
```

And that's it. I tested it out and works on my basic setup.